# Proof: Flow of autonomous ODE satisfies $\varphi_t^{-1} = \varphi_{-t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I keep reading that for an autonomous ODE
$$
\dot{y} = f(y) \qquad \text{with} \qquad y(t_0) = y_0
$$
its flow satisfies $\varphi_t^{-1} = \varphi_{-t}$. That is the inverse of the flow map is the flow map with negative time. I was not able to find a proof of this anywhere.

##### Definition of Flow Map

The flow map is defined as the map $\varphi_t:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that takes an initial condition $y_0 = y(t_0)$ and returns the solution of the ODE after time $t$
$$
y_t = \varphi(y_0) \qquad \text{if}\qquad y_0 = y(t_0)
$$

## Possible Proof

By definition the flow map has two properties

- $\varphi_0$ is the identity map so that $\varphi_0(y_0) = y_0$
- $\varphi_s \circ \varphi_t = \varphi_{s+t}$ semi-group property.

Then taking $s = -t$ one has $\varphi_{-t} \circ \varphi_{t} = \varphi_0 = \text{Id}$ and so $\varphi_{-t}$ is the identity map.

Comment: Your reasoning is right, of course if one assumes this flow is unique.

Comment: @Funktorality Thank you for your comment. I don't know too much about ODEs and their flow. When is the flow not unique? Or rather, when is it guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Look up the Picard–Lindelöf theorem about existence and uniqueness of solutions.